# Varien_Data_Form - 'checkboxes' only save last value

Tags: database, forms, table, checkbox

I made a simple form field with checkboxes

```
            $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
            $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('option_');
            $form->setFieldNameSuffix('option');
            $this->setForm($form);

            $values = array(
                array(
                    label => 'check1',
                    value => 'check1'
                ),
                array(
                    label => 'check2',
                    value => 'check2'
                )
            );

            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'rules',
                array('legend' => 'Rules'
            );

            $fieldset->addField(
                'checks',
                'checkboxes',
                array(
                    'name'  => 'checks',
                    'values'=> $values,
                    'after_element_html' => '<button type="button" onclick="saveAndContinueEdit()">Save</button>'
               )
            );
```

but when I save them, only the last(in array) checked checkbox gets saved in the database.

In my install script I have

```
->addColumn(
    'checks',
    Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k',
    array(),
    'Checkbox Test'
)
```

Why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make the name of the input an array.

So instead of

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'checks',
            'checkboxes',
            array(
                'name'  => 'checks',
                'values'=> $values,
                'after_element_html' => '<button type="button" onclick="saveAndContinueEdit()">Save</button>'
           )
        );
```

use

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'checks',
            'checkboxes',
            array(
                'name'  => 'checks[]',
                'values'=> $values,
                'after_element_html' => '<button type="button" onclick="saveAndContinueEdit()">Save</button>'
           )
        );
```

Comment: It saves 'Array' in the database now. But I feel this is the right approach. Thanks

Comment: That's a totally different issue. You need to get the value send via post for this field in your save action and convert it to string. You can get the value like `$this->getRequest()->getPost('checks');`. And just `implode(',', $value);`.  And when on edit mode you need to `explode` the existing values before passing them to the form.